# A question of case when referring to a floor or level of a building

Tags: capitalization

Can someone please confirm whether the word should start with a capital or not when when the it is used in this context... "We are moving to Level 6, 555 Smith St" or "We are moving to Floor 6, 555 Smith St", rather than "We are moving to level 6, 555 Smith St"

I understand that if it was used like this "Take the stairs to the 6th floor" then lowercase is correct.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe that would depend on zoning law...

Comment: My instinct would be to use a capital letter when using 'Level 6' as a 'name' for the floor.

Comment: I don't think people would normally use "Floor 6" as part of an address, unless you own/rent the entire floor. More common would be "We're moving to the 6th floor of 555 Smith St."